# can I work with angular js ng-repeat and turn.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, turnjs

I'm trying to make a magazine using turn.js and angular.js

I'm using angular to parse the json file and extract the image path for using it in a $scope variable in my view with ng-repeat and the turn.js to make the flipbook animation to make the div look like a magazine.

But it doesnt generate the flipbook and just draw the images one after other.

Please help! I put the code right here

HTML

```
       <div id="flipbook" class="flipbook"ng-repeat="slide in slides">
        <div><img src="{{slide.path_main}}"></div>
       </div>      


</div>
```

Flipbook init

```
   $("#flipbook").turn({
        width: 1724,
        height: 772,
        autoCenter: true
    });
```

Comment: you're using a `class` in your HTML and targeting an `id` in your javascript

Comment: I remove the class and still does'nt work

Comment: any console error ? Can you give us the `flipbook` constructor ?

Comment: what is the console error ? If flipbook is loaded, there should be no problem once the DOM #flipbook is loaded

Comment: no, no console error, it just display the images, like i didnt have turn.js at all, in fact i dont have a script.js file with the constructor of the flipbook, i have it all in the html file

Comment: Maybe a race condition? I'm not familiar with flipbook, but if it's parsing the DOM before ngRepeat adds children you might need to tell it to parse again  via ng-repeat-end

Comment: need to run the code from a directive, and let angular build the html before initializing. Can check for `$last` within `ng-repeat` as a trigger or use API for each element and add page in sub directive

Comment: interesting problem, im not sure but has angular got a composition complete trigger ? -> Post compose trigger ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figure it out by adding the ngrepeat in the inner div of the flipbok! It was such a silly thing but now I have my flipbook perfct!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a `renderComplete` event or anything like that in angular; you may have to use `$timeout` as suggested [here](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering/).

```
// i'm taking assumptions with your code, but...

$scope.slides = [];

$http.get('/data/slides.json').success(function(data){

  $scope.slides = data;

  $timeout(function(){

    $("#flipbook").turn({
      width: 1724,
      height: 772,
      autoCenter: true
    });

  }, 0);

});
```

Comment: even with the `$timeout` the flipbook dont work, the images are drawing one after other