# ng-repeat in the turn.js is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, turn.js

I'm trying to use turn.js in my application. I have found that it is working fine when I just use normal div's but when I use ng-repeat and create several div's , it was not working and just showing the contents of the div instead of the pages.

**app.js file**

```
var test=angular.module('test', [])

test.directive('flipbook', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope : {
      data : '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      $('#flipbook').turn({
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px',
        pages: 8
      });

      $('#flipbook').turn('peel', 'br');
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.show_page = function(page){
        console.log("page", page)
        $('#flipbook').turn('page', page);
      }
    },
    //template : '<div id="flipbook"><div ng-repeat="pageNum in data">{{pageNum}}</div></div>'
    //template : '<div id="flipbook"><div>PAGE {{data[2]}}</div><div>PAGE 1</div></div>'
    templateUrl: "flipbook.html"
  }
});
```

**flipbook.html**

```
<div id="flipbook"><div ng-repeat="pageNum in data">{{pageNum}}</div></div>
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <flipbook data="['1','2','3','4','5','6']"></flipbook>
  </body>
```

Here is the plunker which shows what I'm trying to do. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/6ZDBRXuNvOSX9kyZ2evq?p=preview

Note :- I have checked in internet and found this question , but the answer didn't work for me as that's very old one and didn't worked I'm posting this here hoping for answer. New fixed plunker would be appreciated if possible :)
[can I work with angular js ng-repeat and turn.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752950/can-i-work-with-angular-js-ng-repeat-and-turn-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delay your jquery `turn` function because DOM rendering is not yet complete.

So inject `$timeout` and wrap your function like:

```
$timeout(function(){
        $('#flipbook').turn({
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px',
        pages: 8
       });
       $('#flipbook').turn('peel', 'br');
     }, 0);
```

Here is fixed [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/H4J9JstOgpuLimM12aWw?p=preview)